# EKF localization is approaching singularity. Are my sensors too noisy?

Tags: localization, ekf

I'm getting this warning from Matlab about Kalman Gain.

```
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
         Results may be inaccurate. RCOND = 9.996841e-19.
```

The problem is coming from high variance of the measurement model. My question is here Does EKF work with high noise in sensor?

Comment: It is hard to tell what went wrong here without more information. My guess is that inverting the innovation covariance matrix ($H \bar\Sigma_t H^T + Q_t$) fails due to $Q_t$ being degenerate. EKF does work well with high noise, as long as this noise is still Gaussian. Could you provide the values of your matrix $Q$ and maybe even $H \bar\Sigma_t H^T$ in this case?